# javascript - dry - nested if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am new to coding, but have been reading about DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself.

I have a JavaScript if/else statement that does not fit the DRY approach, but I am unable to workout how to write the JavaScript if/else statement so that the contents are not repeated.

I am hoping some one smarter than me can show me.

Here is my code:

```
    {% if user.get_profile.subscription_category == '00' %}

        $('#id_name_details_prefix_title').addClass('kmw-disabled');

        $('#id_name_details_first_name').addClass('kmw-disabled');

        $('#id_name_details_middle_name').addClass('kmw-disabled');

        $('#id_name_details_last_name').addClass('kmw-disabled');

        $('#id_name_details_suffix_title').addClass('kmw-disabled');

    {% else %}

        {% if user.get_profile.display_virtual_keyboard %}

            $('#id_name_details_prefix_title').removeClass('kmw-disabled');

            $('#id_name_details_first_name').removeClass('kmw-disabled');

            $('#id_name_details_middle_name').removeClass('kmw-disabled');

            $('#id_name_details_last_name').removeClass('kmw-disabled');

            $('#id_name_details_suffix_title').removeClass('kmw-disabled');

        {% else %}

            $('#id_name_details_prefix_title').addClass('kmw-disabled');

            $('#id_name_details_first_name').addClass('kmw-disabled');

            $('#id_name_details_middle_name').addClass('kmw-disabled');

            $('#id_name_details_last_name').addClass('kmw-disabled');

            $('#id_name_details_suffix_title').addClass('kmw-disabled');

        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
```

**The contents of the 1st if are repeated in the else of the 2nd if statement - I am hoping that I only have to write the repeated contents once.**

Comment: That's not JavaScript. Are you generating the code on the server or is that some kind of templating language? Anyway, this might be a better question for [codereview.se].

Comment: @Juhana It could be a Nunjucks template.

Comment: oh yeah - its django template language but in js, however the dry principle is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your selectors in an array

```
var selectors = [#id_name_details_prefix_title', '#id_name_details_first_name' ...];
```

and then add/remove class

```
$(selectors.join(',')).addClass('kmw-disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

Break it up into functions that isolate what's going on.

```
{% if something %}
    functionThathAddsClass();
{% else %}
    {% if something_else %}
        functionThatRemovesClass();
    {% else %}
        functionThathAddsClass();
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

You will run into the problem of creating two global functions in this case, but that's a different issue.

I like to make, what I personally call, CSS Guards.
A CSS Guard is basically just an object that has functions that pokes and prods at the DOM.

```
var NameDetailsGuard = {
    functionThathAddsClass = function () {
        $('#id_name_details_prefix_title').addClass('kmw-disabled');
        $('#id_name_details_first_name').addClass('kmw-disabled');
    },
    functionThatRemovesClass = function () {
        $('#id_name_details_prefix_title').removeClass('kmw-disabled');
        $('#id_name_details_first_name').removeClass('kmw-disabled');
    }
};
```

and you use it like this

```
NameDetailsGuard.functionThatAddsClass();
```

An added benefit to this is that if you expand on this concept you can start doing simpler DOM node caching within this object so that instead of querying for the selector everytime you'll retain a reference to it and manipulate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some class to needed elements (in HTML markup) and select by that class.

For example, add `category-zero` and `virtual-keyboard` classes and use following:

```
{% if user.get_profile.subscription_category == '00' %}

    $('.category-zero').addClass('kmw-disabled');

{% else %}

    {% if user.get_profile.display_virtual_keyboard %}

        $('.virtual-keyboard').removeClass('kmw-disabled');

    {% else %}

        $('.virtual-keyboard').addClass('kmw-disabled');

    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```